# powerline adds hostname when login via ssh

Tags: bash, fedora

I've installed `fedora26 x86_64` on my server machine and have set terminal as screen-256color. I have installed power-line for terminal customization.

I'm using `epsi.json` theme. But when I'm logging in via ssh the power line prompt looks like:

```
test@machine26:~ test> ~ >
test@machine26:~/powerline-gitstatus test> > powerline-
gitstatus >> master ★ v1.2.1 >$
```

But it is expected to look like:

```
test> ~ >
test> > powerline-gitstatus >> master ★ v1.2.1 >$
```

What is wrong? How to remove the user@hostname string from prompt?

Comment: Look for the bash environment variable PS1 being modified somewhere in your bash initialization scripts. Looks like either powerline is only appending to PS1 or that you are prepending something after powerline sets PS1.